# Typescript: how to declare a type that includes all types extending a common type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**TLDR:** Is there a way in Typescript to declare a type that encompasses all types that extend a given interface?

**My specific problem**

I am writing a custom React hook that encapsulates logic for deciding whether or not an element is moused over. It is modelled roughly after [this hook](https://github.com/Lizhooh/react-hooks-use-hover). It exposes a ref that should be able to take any HTMLElement:

`const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);`

The problem is, if I try to use this ref on any specific React element, I get an error telling me that this specific element is not quite `HTMLElement`. For example, if I use it with `HTMLDivElement`, I get this error: `argument of type HTMLElement is not assignable to parameter of type HTMLDivElement`.

Here's [a simple repro case of the problem above in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgCQCoFkAyBRANgUwFt8xYBeGMfAdxQxwONIAoBKAbgChRJYBPJGiwARAJYA3PERLlKNOiIlSmUNl04AzAK5hgUUeBhR80ZvlyD6YyYxmsYAb04wXMHhBAEAdLhABzZgByAAt8ACd8GFEIGHNpUkCAGljcDk4AX05OY1M4DiA)

Obviously, I wouldn't want to list types of all html elements in my hook. Given that `HTMLDivElement` extends the `HTMLElement` type, is there a way of declaring that the type that I am actually after is not strictly `HTMLElement`, but whatever extends `HTMLElement`?

---

**React code example**

source code of the hook

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

type UseHoverType = [React.RefObject<HTMLElement>, boolean];

export default function useHover(): UseHoverType {
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
  let isTouched = false;

  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null); // <-- What should the type be here?

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    if (!isTouched) {
      setIsHovering(true);
    }
    isTouched = false;
  };
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
  };

  const handleTouch = () => {
    isTouched = true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
      element.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouch);

      return () => {
        element.removeEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnter);
        element.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
        element.removeEventListener('touchend', handleTouch);
      };
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  return [ref, isHovering];
}
```

which produces type error if used like this:

```
import useHover from 'path-to-useHover';

const testFunction = () => {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();

  return (
     <div
      ref={hoverRef}
     >
      Stuff
     </div>
  );

}
```

Type error in example above will be:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Property 'align' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLDivElement'.
```

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of "use this ref on any specific React element"? What is the code that doesn't compile for you?

Comment: @TPReal I have added an example of code that breaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are mistaken about the direction of the assignment that fails. If you have an interface `A`, then the type that matches all subclasses of `A` is just called `A`. This way, `HTMLElement` (i.e. is assignable **from**) any HTML element, e.g. `HTMLDivElement`.

This means that if you have a bunch of functions, one of them accepts `HTMLDivElement`, another accepts `HTMLLinkElement` etc, then there is no real type that you can pass to all of them. It would mean you expect to have an element that is both a div and a link and more.

Edited based on your edits of the question:
If the code you have works fine, and your only problem is that it doesn't compile, then just make your `useHover` generic, like this:

```
type UseHoverType<T extends HTMLElement> = [React.RefObject<T>, boolean];

function useHover<T extends HTMLElement>(): UseHoverType<T> {
  const ref = useRef<T>(null); // <-- What should the type be here?
  ...
```

And then:

```
const testFunction = () => {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover<HTMLDivElement>();
```

Something like this will make your code compile fine, without changing its runtime behaviour. I'm unable to tell if the runtime behaviour right now is as desired.

Comment: In my case, I expect to have an element that implements `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` methods. It can be a div, or a span, or a link, etc. So that when I create React's ref, I would say "here is a ref for anything that can add or remove an event listener". And when I pass this ref to React's `div` element I would expect it to work.

But now that I think more about it, I believe you must be right, and if React's `div` element returns `HTMLDivElement` type, there is nothing I could do to convince react's MutableRefObject to accept a more general type.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much; I don't use generics that often and keep forgetting about their power.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected, since HTMLDivElement extends HTMLElement. In your typescirpt playground you mixed it up.  I updated it by switching x and y in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgCQCoFkAyBRANgUwFt8xYBeGMfAdxQxwONIAoBKAbgChRJYBPJGiwARAJYA3PERLlKNOiIlSmUNl04AzAK5hgUUeBhR80ZvlyD6ymaxgBvTjCcweEEAQB0uEAHNmAcgALfAAnfBhRCBhzaVJ-ABpo3A5OAF9OTmNTPg4gA). You want the function to extend HTMLElement and pass y, which is and HTMLDivElement into it. And that works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Trouble is, my original playground better reflects the problem. I can't change the type that React's `div` element constructor returns — it will always be `HTMLDivElement`. Likewise, a `span` would return `HTMLSpanElement`, and so on. The only type I can define is the type of the useRef function (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L923), and I was trying to come up with a type that would encompass all the types that extend HTMLElement.

Comment: You could just use useRef<any>, but that sucks. You could also hack it like this: ref={inputEl as any as ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void)}